# Are questions about AutoCAD usage on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

Are questions about general AutoCAD usage on topic here (not for any specific field, I'm just teaching myself how to use it as a general skill)?

There is the [CAD proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad), but it's just a proposal, and doesn't have much steam. Searching Area51 for "cad" yields [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) as a result, but after a quick look through the questions there it doesn't seem like the correct place.

There is [Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188052/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-autocad-questions), which is what led me here. The accepted answer is for Blender, which the OP was asking about, but I'm not using Blender. The next best answer mentioned SU and SO. My question is about general usage rather than scripting, so SO is not the right place for it. The remaining answers mentioned the CAD proposal. The post is 2 years old, as well, so not sure how up-to-date it is.

That leaves SU as a candidate, but [a look at the *autocad* tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autocad?sort=votes&pageSize=15) is disheartening. Of the few well-received questions there, the majority are about installation issues and such, only a few about usage and those are a few years old.

So, would those kinds of AutoCAD software usage questions be acceptable here? I see myself having a number of them in the near future.

Failing SU, I would just head to the Autodesk forums. SE seems to be a bit lacking in the CAD department, unfortunately, but I thought it would be worth trying here first.

Comment: Software is software well written detailed questions will be accepted unresearched questions won't be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure why not?

Consider a few things though. *Using* autocad is specialised so you may not get an answer (immediately?) - general usage questions should definately be in our scope tho